# JQuery: How do I get a DID ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="house">...</div>
```

But in my code I dynamically insert in DIV ID's to make the code then look like this:

```
<div class="house" id="id_1">...</div>
```

**Question**: How can I get the DIV ID by only knowing the CLASS using JQuery?  I've tried something like the following but it doesn't work.

```
$('.house').getID();
```

Comment: "I tried `.getID()` but it doesn't work."  LOL maybe you should review the library documentation before blindly using it!

Answer (score 9):

```
$('div.house')
  .each(function(index) {
    alert( 'id for this div.class #'+index+': '+$(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: +1: it's good to note that there may be a number of different IDs based on the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get and set attributes.

```
var houseId = $('.house').attr('id');
```

Note: This will only get the last '.house' element in the DOM's id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
$('.house').attr("id");
```

Should work. I didn't test it though.